# Let $A, B, C$ be subgroups of $D$, where $A \le B$, $A \cap C = B \cap C$, and $AC=BC$. Show $A=B$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A,B, C \le D.$ (*i.e.*,  $A, B, C$ are subgroups of $D$), where $A \le B$, $A \cap C = B \cap C$, and $AC=BC$. Show $A=B$.

I've entertained commutative diagrams as a way to show this, but I'm having difficulty showing this more formally. Intuitively, it makes sense, but I'm not sure how to incorporate $AC = BC$.

Answer (score 3):

Without the assumption that $AC=BC$, the conclusion that $A=B$ does not follow. For example, in the dihedral group $D_8$ of order $8$, if you take $A=\langle r^2\rangle$, $B=\langle  r\rangle$, and $C=\langle s\rangle$, then $A\leq B$, $A\cap C=B\cap C=\{e\}$, but $A\neq B$. However, that example does not satisfy $AC=BC$.

Since you already know that $A\subseteq B$, you just need to show that $B\subseteq A$. Let $b\in B$. We want to show that $b\in A$. We know that $b\in B\subseteq BC=AC$, so there exists $a\in A$ and $c\in C$ such that $b=ac$. Then $c=a^{-1}b$. Since $a\in A\leq B$, then $a^{-1}b\in B$.

Can you finish it from there?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Comment: It was not me - I upvoted!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin How would you continue from here? I can't see it.

Comment: @JellyHops: Note that $a^{-1}b\in B$, but $c\in C$. Look also for the assumption we haven’t used yet.